# From AS3 to C# a simple elapsed Timer

Tags: c#, timer

I need to set up a simple elapsed Timer in C# (MonoBehavior) that calls a method when complete, but can also be cancelled before finishing. If cancelled or stopped, it automatically resets its interval. I don't need anything fancy like threading.
Reading over the documentation on C# Timers 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Timers.Timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
still a bit confused. For instance, when you set *mytimer.Enabled=false* does it also reset the timer back to 0? 
 Perhaps I should be looking at Coroutines instead?(this is for Unity)

In AS3 I would do something like this

```
private var _delayTimer:Timer;

//create a Timer object that runs once for 1 second
_delayTimer = new Timer(1000,1);

//add handler
_delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.COMPLETE, onDelay);


//start timer
_delayTimer.start();


private function onDelay(e:TimerEvent):void{
trace('delay finished!);
}

//some other method to interrupt-stop and reset the delay timer
private function foo():void{
_delayTimer.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `System.Timers.Timer`, you *are* using multi-threading - it's quite likely this is not what you want.

Instead, you probably want `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` - this will post the timer event back on the UI thread (if you're using Windows Forms, of course).

You can use `Start` and `Stop` the way you want, because there's actually no ticking clock - it just registers a callback from Windows in the future, basically.

Relevant piece of documentation from MSDN:

> Calling Start after you have disabled a Timer by calling Stop will cause the Timer to restart the interrupted interval. If your Timer is set for a 5000-millisecond interval, and you call Stop at around 3000 milliseconds, calling Start will cause the Timer to wait 5000 milliseconds before raising the Tick event.